# How to catch the play.api.libs.openid.Errors$AUTH_CANCEL$ exception?

Tags: exception, openid, playframework-2.1

Using Play Framework 2.1 with OpenID, if I cancel my authentication from the OpenID Provider, I get this exception :

```
[RuntimeException: play.api.libs.openid.Errors$AUTH_CANCEL$]
```

Here's my code :

```
Promise<UserInfo> userInfoPromise = OpenID.verifiedId();
UserInfo userInfo = userInfoPromise.get(); // Exception thrown here
```

But since it's a Runtime exception, I can't catch it with a try/catch so I'm stuck on how to avoid exception and returns something nicer than a server error to the client.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Promise is success biased, for all its operations, it assumes it actually contains a value and not an error.
You get the exception because you try to call `get` on a promise  which contains an untransformed error.

What you want is to determine if the Promise is a success or an error, you can do that with pattern matching for instance.

try this code:

```
AsyncResult(
      OpenID.verifiedId.extend1( _ match {
        case Redeemed(info) => Ok(info.attributes.get("email").getOrElse("no email in valid response"))
        case Thrown(throwable) => {
          Logger.error("openid callback error",throwable)
          Unauthorized
        }
      }
      )
    )
```

You may want to read more on future and promises, I recommend this excellent article :
http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/09/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-8-welcome-to-the-future.html

edit : 
checking the documentation (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaOpenID) in java it seems you are supposed to catch and handle exceptions yourself.

> In any case, you should catch exceptions and if one is thrown redirect
>   back the user to the login page with relevant information.

something like this should work :

```
public class Application extends Controller {


    public static Result index() {
        return ok("welcome");
    }

    public static Result auth() {
        Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        attributes.put("email", "http://schema.openid.net/contact/email");
        final Promise<String> stringPromise = OpenID.redirectURL("https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id", "http://localhost:9000/auth/callback",attributes);
        return redirect(stringPromise.get());
    }


    public static Result callback() {
        try{
            Promise<UserInfo> userInfoPromise = OpenID.verifiedId();
            final UserInfo userInfo = userInfoPromise.get();
            System.out.println("id:"+userInfo.id);
            System.out.println("email:"+userInfo.attributes.get("email"));
            return ok(userInfo.attributes.toString());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return unauthorized();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I'd like to test it, but my code is in Java :/ Could you provide the Java code alternative, it would be great! :)